# Why does the command "perf list" produce different outputs on the same version RedHat Linux?

Tags: linux, list, redhat, perf

I got two RedHat Linux machine with the same OS version, but for the command `perf list`, it produces different outputs.

The first machine:

> cat /proc/version
>
> Linux version 2.6.32-279.11.1.el6.x86_64
>   (mockbuild@ca-build44.us.oracle.com) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red
>   Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Oct 16 08:03:36 PDT 2012
>
> perf --version
>
> perf version 3.0.36-300.17.1.el6uek.x86_64

On this machine, `perf list` couldn't list out any tracepoint events.

The second machine:

> cat /proc/version
>
> Linux version 2.6.32-279.11.1.el6.x86_64
>   (mockbuild@ca-build44.us.oracle.com) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red
>   Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Oct 16 08:03:36 PDT 2012
>
> perf --version
>
> perf version 3.0.36-300.17.1.el6uek.x86_64

On this machine, `perf list` could list out all events

Answer (score 1):

May be the first machine has no tracepoint support.

For the tracepoint events you will need to have debugfs mounted first, e.g.

```
mount -t debugfs none /dbg
```

And you might also need ftrace enabled in kernel.